# Show current day in the middle

Tags: php, date

I have a while loop that shows 5 days. The first day is the current day and the other ones are the next 4. This is my code:

```
$datetime = new \DateTime();

$listItem = array('<li class="active">', '</li>');

$i = 0;
while (true) {
    if ($i === 5) break;

    if ($datetime->format('N') === '7' && $i === 0) {
        $datetime->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'));
        continue;        
    }

    echo $listItem[0] . $datetime->format('D d-m') . $listItem[1];
    $listItem = array('<li>', '</li>');    

    $datetime->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'));

    $i++;
}
```

The result looks like this: 
[image]

My problem is, I want the current day to be in the middle. Where saturday is should be the current day. Do you know how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try Below Code :

```
$datetime = new \DateTime();

$listItem = array('<li">', '</li>');
$listItem_active = array('<li class="active">', '</li>');

$i = 0;
while (true) {

    if ($i === 5) break;

    if ($datetime->format('N') === '7' && $i === 0) {
        $datetime->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'));
        continue;        
    }

    if($i===0){
        $today = $datetime->format('D d-m');
    }
    if($i===3){
        echo $listItem_active[0] . $today . $listItem_active[1];
    }
    if($i!=0){
        echo $listItem[0] . $datetime->format('D d-m') . $listItem[1];
    }

    $listItem = array('<li>', '</li>');    

    $datetime->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'));

    $i++;
}
```

Comment: I wanted the middle day to have a distinct class like "active" or something do u know how to do this?

Comment: One thing is that the next day appears above ,i dont know how to make friday appear under thursday.

Answer (score 1):

```
$datetime = new \DateTime();
$datetime->modify('-2 Day');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php

Comment: Now the first day still has the "<li> with the active class" can i make the current day have the active class? –

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

You could simply subtract 2 days from your starting day like this.

```
$datetime = new \DateTime();
$datetime->sub(new \DateInterval('P2D'));
```

Comment: Now the first day still has the "<li> with the active class"  can i make the current day have the active class?