# Date order 2 days ahead

Tags: php

```
$datetime = new \DateTime();


$listItem = array('<li">', '</li>');
$listItem_active = array('<li class="active-day">', '</li>');

$i = 0;
while (true) {

    if ($i === 5) break;

    if ($datetime->format('N') === '7' && $i === 0) {
        $datetime->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'));
        continue;        
    }

    if($i===0){
        $today = $datetime->format('D d-m');
    }
    if($i===3){
        echo $listItem_active[0] . $today . $listItem_active[1];
    }
    if($i!=0){
        echo $listItem[0] . $datetime->format('D d-m') . $listItem[1];
    }

    $listItem = array('<li>', '</li>');    

    $datetime->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'));

    $i++;
}
```

I have the above code made and its almost right, but the output is not exactly how i want it. I get the following output: 
[image]

The current day should always be in the middle. as you can see this works. but the order of the days is not as i desire. The order i desire is this :

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show current day in the middle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44048393/show-current-day-in-the-middle)

Comment: @PedroLobito this is an entire different question though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`strtotime`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to get these results and the code will be much shorter.

For example:

```
for ($i = 2; $i > -3; $i--)
{
    echo date('D d-m', strtotime($i . ' days ago')) . '<br />';
}
```

will output:

```
Tue 16-05
Wed 17-05
Thu 18-05
Fri 19-05
Sat 20-05
```

Comment: wow, this is way shorter and it does exactly what i want haha, thanks

Comment: In the future i want to highlight the current date, how can i distinct this day from the other with like a special class?

Comment: In my example, you could check if `$i === 0` in the loop